# Orthogonality of periodic function

Tags: orthogonality, periodic-functions

I have a problem with proving this:

$\text{For} \ s(x)=\begin{cases} -1, \ -1<x<0 \\ 1, \ 0<x<1\end{cases}, \ s(x+2)=s(x), \ \text{Prove that each s(kx) (k=1,2,3,...) is orthogonal, that is,} \ \int_{-1}^1 s(ix)s(jx)dx=0 \ \text{for i}\neq\text{j}.$

How Can I prove this? I have no idea about any approaches.

Comment: Use induction. Can you prove it for $i=1,\ j=2$?

Comment: @Berci, After I start induction by the case of i=1 and j=2, how can I proceed the induction step with two variables i and j with i≠j?

Comment: When $i = 1$ and $j = 3$, the integral equals $2/3$, the proposition therefore seems false.

Comment: @Rémy Sigrist, Thank you for check.